# In magento how to add or remove a link in header

Tags: magento

I want to know how to create a link in magento header and also need to know how to remove the previously added links in header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add like this for your custom link to set in magento header

```
<default>
<reference name="top.links">
  <action method="addLink" translate="label title">
    <label>Terms and Condition</label>
    <url>terms</url>
    <title>Terms and Condition</title>
    <prepare>true</prepare>
    <position>2</position>
  </action>
</reference>
</default>
```

- See more at: http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-add-top-links-in-magento

Also see this

http://www.techdilate.com/code/magento-add-remove-top-links-using-layout-xml/

*i am not associate with above link for any. this is only for knowledge sharing purpose.*

Comment: in your theme's local.xml if you have. or relevant xml as define in above link

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer you want is at:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/6237/